# make -jN blocks on second run when using an order-only prerequisite in sub-sub-target

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile

I've been having a very strange problem with a Makefile using order-only prerequisite and parallel mode:

- when running in sequential mode, the first time the Makefile does its job, and the next times, it just does nothing and returns, as expected.
- when running in parallel mode (-j4 for instance), the first time it does its job, but the next times it just hangs. The process is blocked doing nothing, it doesn't even exit. However it is still responsive in the sense that if I terminate it using Ctrl-C, it cleans the intermediate files it may have created and eventually stops.

In parallel mode, if I `make clean`, it runs again without problem. Likewise, if I just `touch` **all** the source files, it works (again, in parallel mode). However if I `touch` **some** of the source files, it runs fine until it's done with them, then it hangs.

So I created a minimal working example, the main folder contains only a folder named 'txt' with some *.txt file in it (could be any file) and the Makefile

```
TXT_FILES = $(shell ls txt/*.txt)
A_FILES = $(patsubst txt/%.txt, a/%.txt, $(TXT_FILES))

all: a

a: $(A_FILES)

dir:
    @if [ ! -d "a" ]; then echo "create directory a" && mkdir -p a; fi

a/tmp_%: txt/%.txt | dir
    @echo "creating tmp file"
    @cp $< $@

a/%.txt: a/tmp_%
    @echo creating $@
    @cp $< $@

clean: clean-dir

clean-dir:
    rm -rf a

.PHONY: all a
.PRECIOUS: a/%.txt
```

What it does for this test is:

1. list files in txt (file1.txt, ..., fileN.txt)
2. create directory 'a' if it doesn't exist
3. copy each file from 'txt' in a temporary file 'a/tmp_fileN'
4. copy each temporary file from 'a/tmp_fileN' into its final destination 'a/fileN.txt'

In order to avoid recopying all the files from 'txt' into 'a' every time I call make, I use an order-only prerequisite for the 'dir' prerequisite of the `a/tmp_%` target.

Please note that the original Makefile does much more complicated things which makes the use of a temporary file necessary, I kept it in this example to reproduce the problematic behavior (without the `a/tmp_%` target, and putting the | dir to the `a/%.txt` target, no problem occurs).

Here is the log with --debug (I translated from French, so the terms might be approximate):

```
Reading makefiles...
Update targets....
 File « all » doesn't exist.
   File « a » doesn't exist.
        File « dir » doesn't exist.
       Must rebuild target « dir ».
 File « all » doesn't exist.
   File « a » doesn't exist.
 File « all » doesn't exist.
   File « a » doesn't exist.
 File « all » doesn't exist.
   File « a » doesn't exist.
 File « all » doesn't exist.
   File « a » doesn't exist.
 ...
```

and it loops over these two messages over and over again. But if this is some kind of circular dependency, I fail to see it (besides the first run of `make` wouldn't work, would it ?).

This is 100% reproducible on two different hardwares with two different versions of Linux (CentOS 6.3 and Ubuntu 12.04), both using GNU Make 3.81

**Update**: As pointed out in the answer from Etan (and related comments), the problem is actually twofold:

1. even when there is nothing to do, make runs some target. This can be solved with proper renaming of the targets and directories
2. without the fix for point 1, make hangs in parallel mode when there is nothing to do in the example above. This is likely some sort of bug or limitation in make 3.81 since an update to 3.82 (or 4.0) solves it (note that if solution to point 1 is applied, the problem doesn't occur either, so no need to update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the clue that make is giving you that something in your makefile isn't quite right and work our way up, shall we?

Add:

```
donothing: static
        touch '$@'
```

to the makefile (we'll use this in a minute).

Here's our starting directory structure:

```
$ ls -R
.:
Makefile  static  txt

./txt:
1.txt
```

Let us run `make` once:

```
$ make
create directory a
creating tmp file
creating a/1.txt
rm a/tmp_1
```

Now run `make donothing` once:

```
$ make donothing
touch 'donothing'
```

Now 'make' again:

```
$ make
```

Now 'make donothing' again:

```
$ make donothing
make: `donothing' is up to date
```

See the difference in the output there? That's the clue. `make` believes there is something to do for your default target even when it doesn't actually do any work (that we can see).

Our current directory structure (just for completeness):

```
$ ls -R
.:
Makefile  a  donothing  static  txt

./a:
1.txt

./txt:
1.txt
```

So what does `make` do when we run `make donothing`?

```
$ make -rRd donothing
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `donothing'.
  Considering target file `static'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `static'.
   No implicit rule found for `static'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `static'.
  No need to remake target `static'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `donothing'.
 Prerequisite `static' is older than target `donothing'.
No need to remake target `donothing'.
make: `donothing' is up to date.
```

And what does `make` do when the default target is run?

```
$ make
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `a'.
   File `a' does not exist.
    Considering target file `a/1.txt'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file `a/tmp_1'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite `txt/1.txt'.
      Trying rule prerequisite `dir'.
     Found an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
       Considering target file `txt/1.txt'.
        Looking for an implicit rule for `txt/1.txt'.
        No implicit rule found for `txt/1.txt'.
        Finished prerequisites of target file `txt/1.txt'.
       No need to remake target `txt/1.txt'.
       Considering target file `dir'.
        File `dir' does not exist.
        Finished prerequisites of target file `dir'.
       Must remake target `dir'.
Putting child 0x0af5df90 (dir) PID 15558 on the chain.
Live child 0x0af5df90 (dir) PID 15558
Reaping winning child 0x0af5df90 PID 15558
Removing child 0x0af5df90 PID 15558 from chain.
       Successfully remade target file `dir'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `a/1.txt'.
     Prerequisite `a/tmp_1' of target `a/1.txt' does not exist.
    No need to remake target `a/1.txt'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `a'.
  Must remake target `a'.
  Successfully remade target file `a'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
```

Ah hah.

`make` believes it needs to rebuild the `dir` target (even though it doesn't do anything) but there isn't a file there to tell make otherwise so it has to try. So that's why it doesn't print "nothing to do" because there is something to do.

So let us give `make` the information it needs to know that it *doesn't* need to run the `dir` target every time. The simplest way to do that is to touch a file with that name. (Note that this isn't actually *correct* since with this `make` will **never** run the `dir` target again as it has no prerequisites but we'll get to that in a bit.)

Change:

```
dir:
        @if [ ! -d "a" ]; then echo "create directory a" && mkdir -p a; fi
```

to

```
dir:
        @if [ ! -d "a" ]; then echo "create directory a" && mkdir -p a; fi
        touch dir
```

Also add `dir` to the `clean` rule:

```
clean: clean-dir
        rm -f dir
```

Now let us run `make` again:

```
$ make
touch dir
```

Good. That made the file we wanted.

Let's see what happens when we run `make` again:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Good. That's what we wanted.

Shall we try with `-j4` now?

```
$ make clean
$ make -j4
create directory a
touch dir
creating tmp file
creating a/1.txt
rm a/tmp_1
$ make -j4
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Great. That looks like it worked.

We should check the `-d` output to be sure though:

```
$ make -j4 -rRd
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `a'.
   File `a' does not exist.
    Considering target file `a/1.txt'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file `a/tmp_1'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite `txt/1.txt'.
      Trying rule prerequisite `dir'.
     Found an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
       Considering target file `txt/1.txt'.
        Looking for an implicit rule for `txt/1.txt'.
        No implicit rule found for `txt/1.txt'.
        Finished prerequisites of target file `txt/1.txt'.
       No need to remake target `txt/1.txt'.
       Considering target file `dir'.
        Finished prerequisites of target file `dir'.
       No need to remake target `dir'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `a/1.txt'.
     Prerequisite `a/tmp_1' of target `a/1.txt' does not exist.
    No need to remake target `a/1.txt'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `a'.
  Must remake target `a'.
  Successfully remade target file `a'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

So that seems to have been the problem. Ok.

Now, remember how I said this wasn't actually a good solution? Here's why:

```
$ rm -rf a
$ .:
Makefile  dir  donothing  static  txt

./txt:
1.txt
$ make
creating tmp file
cp: cannot create regular file `a/tmp_1': No such file or directory
$ ls
Makefile  dir  donothing  static  txt
```

Oops. The `a` directory didn't get created because `make` didn't realize it needed to run the `dir` target again.

Relevant snippet of `make -rRd` output since this is getting a bit long:

```
$ make -rRd
....
       Considering target file `dir'.
        Finished prerequisites of target file `dir'.
       No need to remake target `dir'.
....
```

So how should we fix this? Well, we can stop using such indirect rules and let make know about the *real* prerequisite information where it wants it.

So we start by dropping the `.PHONY` `a` target that just confuses things.

```
all: $(A_FILES)

.PHONY: all
```

and remove the `a: $(A_FILES)` line.

But that's not enough since we still have the `dir` prerequisite confusing things and behaving badly.

But since we no longer have a target that matches our directory name and we know how to use order-only prerequisites to get directory creation behaviour we can use that.

Replace `dir:` with `a:` and `| dir` with `| a` (and drop `rm -f dir` from the `clean` rule since we don't need it anymore) and we end up with:

```
TXT_FILES = $(shell ls txt/*.txt)
A_FILES = $(patsubst txt/%.txt, a/%.txt, $(TXT_FILES))

all: $(A_FILES)

a:
        @if [ ! -d "a" ]; then echo "create directory a" && mkdir -p a; fi

a/tmp_%: txt/%.txt | a
        @echo "creating tmp file"
        @cp $< $@

a/%.txt: a/tmp_%
        @echo creating $@
        @cp $< $@

clean: clean-dir

clean-dir:
        rm -rf a

.PHONY: all
.PRECIOUS: a/%.txt

donothing: static
        touch '$@'
```

Does that work?

```
$ ls -R
.:
Makefile  donothing  static  txt

./txt:
1.txt
$ make
create directory a
creating tmp file
creating a/1.txt
rm a/tmp_1
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make -j4
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make clean
rm -rf a
$ make -j4
create directory a
creating tmp file
creating a/1.txt
rm a/tmp_1
$ make -j4
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Looks like it.

And for good measure:

```
$ make -j4 -rRd
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `a/1.txt'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `a/tmp_1'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `a/tmp_1'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `1'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `txt/1.txt'.
    Trying rule prerequisite `a'.
   Found an implicit rule for `a/1.txt'.
     Considering target file `txt/1.txt'.
      Looking for an implicit rule for `txt/1.txt'.
      No implicit rule found for `txt/1.txt'.
      Finished prerequisites of target file `txt/1.txt'.
     No need to remake target `txt/1.txt'.
     Considering target file `a'.
      Finished prerequisites of target file `a'.
     No need to remake target `a'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `a/1.txt'.
   Prerequisite `a/tmp_1' of target `a/1.txt' does not exist.
  No need to remake target `a/1.txt'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Whew! I hope you followed all of that. We covered a good bit of ground there.

One last parting comment: You don't need to shell out to `ls` to get that list of files. You can use `$(wildcard txt/*.txt)` instead.

Comment: Great! this helped very much solving the problem. Only difference is that I have to keep the `a: $(A_FILES)` target because the various targets (and folder naming as well) in my parallel Makefile have to be backward compatible with the one in the original sequential Makefile (drop-in replacement). Luckily, the files actually go into a folder named a/foo, so I created a target `a/foo` that does the `mkdir -p a/foo` if needed and that I use as my prerequisite.

Comment: Forgot to ask: would you know why the parallel make was hanging and not the sequential one ? (or is that a topic for another question ?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know actually. I don't fully understand that myself. Looking at the `-d` output make knows that it already considered the `dir` rule after the first time but then keeps looping for some reason anyway.

Comment: I should also mention that apparently make 3.82 and 4.0 don't loop forever in this case (though they still have the "doing something" issue with the original makefile).

Comment: Most likely a bug.  GNU make 3.81 was released in 2006.  Some few bugs have been fixed since then.

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed. I keep wondering how much fun I'm going to have moving to 3.82 (and then 4.0) when the time comes for that. "Luckily" 4.0 doesn't seem to be on the horizon in the forseeable future (unless I decide to build it myself).

Comment: I just tested the actual large Makefile with self-compiled GNU make 3.82 and it worked like a breeze (even without your fix, but I'll keep using it wherever I can, it's cleaner). Most of my other projects use CMake to generate their Makefiles, so the migration to 3.82 shouldn't be too painful.